# Maximum call stack size error in running a simple recursive function

Tags: javascript

I'm pretty new to JavaScript programming but I had experience in so many other programming languages. The idea of **recursive functions** in JavaScript is a fresh subject for me and I didn't see anything similar in other languages that I worked with. So for the sake of practicing, I decided to write some of the programs that I already have written with "for loops".

One of these programs is a function that takes a string as its argument and reports how many B letters are in it. Using objective-oriented programming, I first declared a function that can find the number of any other characters within a string. The program is as follows,

```
function countChar(string, char) {
  let counted = 0;
  for (let index = 0; index < string.length; index++) {
    if (string[index].toUpperCase() == char.toUpperCase()) {
      counted += 1;
    }
  }
  return counted;
}

function countBs(text) {
  return countChar(text, 'B');
}

console.log(countBs('Baby'));
// output = 2
```

It works very well but now that I'm using recursive functions, I get the **"Maximum call stack size" error**. My program with recursive functions looks like this one,

```
function countChar(string, char) {
  function cursor(i, counted) {
    if (i == string.length) {
      return counted;
    } else if (string[i].toUpperCase() == char.toUpperCase()) {
      return cursor(i++, counted++);
    } else {
      return cursor(i++, counted);
    }
  }
  return cursor(0,0);
}

function countBs(text) {
  return countChar(text, 'B');
}

console.log(countBs('Baby'));
// output must be 2 but I get 'Maximum call stack size' error instead :(
```

Can anybody offers a modification to this program in order to get the solution? Is it basically possible to write this program by using the recursive functions?

Comment: Consider renaming `string` and `char` to some not-so-system names.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

because

```
 return cursor(i++, counted++);
```

has to be

```
 return cursor(i + 1, counted + 1);
```

*(as you want to increase the value passed recursively, not the local variable i)*

---

How i would do that:

```
 const countBs = (str, i = 0) => 
    i >= str.length
      ? 0
      : countBs(str, i + 1) + (str[i].toUpperCase() === "B");
```

Or if you plan to use it for very very long strings, allow for TCO:

```
 function countBs(str, i = 0, count = 0) {
   if(i >= str.length) return count;
   return countBs(str, i + 1, count + (str[i].toUpperCase === "B"));
}
```

Comment: @JonasWilms So "++" operator just works locally? Is that why it works fine with `index++` in for loop?

Comment: @saeed it evaluates to `index`, and then afterwards increases it.